# PHP Foreach as json

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to foreach some data using PHP & Laravel. So I need my data to list like:

```
{'RS': 100, 'BG': 32, 'LT': 556, 'DE': 34, 'ES': 122, 'GR': 515, 'RO': 422, 'CZ': 223, 'PL': 990, 'HR': 99}
```

But so far I didn't manage to do it. I did something with array_push but no success.
This is how code looks like:

```
$countries =  Countries::where('isActive', 1)->orderBy('isActive', 'DESC')->get();

        $list = array();
        foreach($countries as $key => $country){
            array_push($list, [$country['iso_alpha_2'] => 1]);

        }
        
        return response()->json($list);
```

And current output is:

```
[
    {
        "LU": 1
    },
    {
        "RS": 1
    },
    {
        "UZ": 1
    },
    {
        "SI": 1
    },
    {
        "PR": 1
    },
    {
        "HR": 1
    }
]
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Instead of array_push, you want `$list[$country['iso_alpha_2']] = $someValue;` What exactly `$someValue` is, we can’t know, because your code just assigned `1` for those values, that you actually want to be 100, 32, 556, etc. Only you can know where those are supposed to come from here in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, it was easy fix.

```
$countries =  Countries::where('isActive', 1)->orderBy('isActive', 'DESC')->get();

        foreach($countries as $key => $country){
            $list[$country['iso_alpha_2']] = 2;
        }
        
        return response()->json($list);
```